# "allow me a day's absence" sounds wrong to me. How do I phrase it better?

Tags: phrasing

How do I phrase this line better -

"<..Blah Blah.. Explaining what my problems are..>. It'll be really helpful if you can allow me a day's absence. Would this be possible?"

Comment: Just say *“It’d be really helpful if you could give me a day off.”*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a writing advice request.

Answer (score 2):

In BrEng "allow me a day's absence" is perfectly OK but quite formal. It all depends who you are asking and whether you feel you can be less formal, in which case use Cyberherbalist's alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, I would be asking to take one day of my annual leave.

*Day off* sounds a bit like a special favour, and possibly without pay.

Depending on the industry and situation, taking a day of one's annual leave allowance ought to be a reasonable request.

Comment: +1.  I'd say "allow me a day's leave".  Especially as we have various types of leave here: Sick leave, holiday leave, maternity leave, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that there may be a difference between British and American on this point, "allow me a day's absence" is OK, but would be more likely to be phrased "allow me a day off" or even better "could let me have a day off".

Anyway, a "day off" or an "hour off" is the way to put it.  "Off" in this case means to be "off work".